# Windows Azure SDK 2.0 missing in cloud service?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

We just upgraded from the Windows Azure 1.7 SDK to 2.0.

This created a lot of problems in the codebase, but we got them ironed out and running locally.

Now when we try to publish to our cloud service machine in Azure, the worker role keeps trying to run but can't start.

My guess is that the cloud service machine is missing the 2.0 SDK.

Is there some way to install this manually on the remote machine? I can RDP and I've been looking around, but I can't seem to a) Verify which version it's trying to use and b) How to install a newer SDK.

I've found some errors about the worker role not running, but they're pretty uninformative.

Comment: Update: One problem was that my Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll was set to "Copy local: false". Set it to true and now the error is "Requested registry access is not allowed."

Comment: Are you running your process with Elevated privileges?

Comment: Since you can RDP, can you look in the event logs? Anything in there? Also, since you are on the 2.0 SDK, you can enable logging through Visual Studio very easily, I would recommend turning the events logs ALL on and use verbose logging to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being pretty simply, but I imagine other people will run into this problem.

We had 5-7 projects all referencing Azure SDK 1.8. Specifically these libraries:

- Microsoft.ServiceBus
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRunTime
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient

If the project is a cloud service project, you need to right click on the project, go to properties, and upgrade the project. This changes the deployment when publishing. It will create the Azure VM based on the cloud service Azure SDK version. I missed that at first.

All the libraries above need to be upgraded to SDK 2.0 in all projects. Initially I missed some projects that were dependencies - and missing the Microsoft.ServiceBus library.

The last part was moving from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.  I guess for SDK 2.0 they changed the library name, which has also introduced some breaking code changes.

After all that the cloud service now publishes correctly. Whew.